# Using Google API distance Matrix with xmlhttp request give XMLHttpRequest Cannot load

Tags: javascript, google-api, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Google API and XMLHTTPRequest to retrieve address information with out any issues.

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"+ data +"&sensor=true", true);
```

But when I try to retrieve information using the distancematrix the following error:

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+data.lat1+","+data.lng1+"&destinations="+data.lat2+","+data.lng2+"&mode=driving&language=pl-PL", true);

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=46.4576003,…4169999999&destinations=51.2769239,-114.021174&mode=driving&language=pl-PL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It's happening because of CORS, Cross Origin Resource Sharing. There are restrictions on making requests to a domain that's different than your own. I understand it but idk how to fix it, I'm sure someone else will let you know soon

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/